# Generating the n-th number with k bits set, is it possible?

Tags: algorithms, reductions, dynamic-programming, combinatorics

## Generating numbers with $k$ bits set for a poker simulation

### Context

I'm trying to generate all possible [Texas Hold'em](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texas_hold_%27em) games for $p$ players, which means there will be at most $2 \cdot p + 5$ cards at play.

To make things a little bit easier, I figured that I could use a 64-bit number to represent each of the cards in a standard 52-card deck (from $2^0$ through $2^{51}$) and represent a full game as the sum of any $2 \cdot p + 5$ distinct 64-bit numbers.

For example, if in my ordering, the suit order is *clubs, diamonds, hearts, spades*, then $1$ would be the ace of clubs ($1♣$), $2$ would be the ace of diamonds ($1♦$), and so on. At the end of the deck will be the king of spades ($K♠$) with a numerical value of $2^{51} = 2\,251\,799\,813\,685\,248$ (quite big). This way, the number $2^{51} + 2^1 + 2^0$ uniquely represents a player's hand of $K♠1♦1♣$.

### Example with two players

Plugging in $p=2$ yields a total of $9$ cards at play for a two-player Texas Hold'em game.

This means that any sum of nine distinct numbers from the set described above would represent a valid game of Texas Hold'em poker with two players. For example, the decimal number $511_d$ in binary is $1\,1111\,1111_b$ and the number $991_d$ in binary is $11\,1101\,1111_b$.

### What I've tried

My initial strategy was to iterate over all 64-bit numbers, checking each number to see if it has $9$ bits set with an algorithm I found online, but I realized I probably wouldn't be alive anymore by the time it finished.

I then thought that maybe I could generate a few terms of each $k$ algorithmically and then fit a polynomial through them to "predict" the next terms, but that was a dead end as well.

So I was wondering if there exists a closed-form expression to yield the $n$-th number that has $k$-bits set to $1$ in its binary representation ($k=9$ in the two-player example).

Comment: You won't be alive when this finishes, but hopefully you will still be alive at the next power cut :-)

Comment: Your goal is unclear. Do you want to enumerate all numbers of $k$ ones, or count the number of ones in a given number ? Or generate random numbers with $k$ ones ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust My goal would be the first option: enumerating all numbers up to a certain cut-off number which all have a population count of $k$ (i.e. $k$ ones).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called *Enumerative Coding* and was introduced by Tom Cover. Consider a word $W$ that is $n$ bits long, where the one bits  are in locations  $x_k, \ldots, x_1$ with $x_k>x_{k-1}>\cdots>x_1$ and the locations are labelled from $0$ to $n-1.$

The position of this word in the lexicographic ordering of all words with exactly $k$ $1$ bits set is an integer which we conveniently start at $0$ (due to the formula used):

$$\textrm{Position}(W)=\sum_{1 \le i \le k} { x_i \choose i}.$$

So, for example, for a 6-bit word with $3$ bits set:

$$\textrm{Position}(000111) = { 2 \choose 3 } + {1 \choose 2 } + {0 \choose 1} = 0$$
$$\textrm{Position}(001011) = { 3 \choose 3 } + {1 \choose 2 } + {0 \choose 1} = 1$$
$$\textrm{Position}(111000) = { 5 \choose 3 } + {4 \choose 2 } + {3 \choose 1} = 19$$

Note that the binomial coefficient
$\binom{n}{k}=0$ if $n<k.$ The first word $000111$ has index zero and the last word $111000$ has index $19.$
There are $\binom{6}{3}=20$ such words so this checks out.

You would apply this with $n=64,$ and $k=9,$ etc.

**Edit:** *Inverse mapping*

For the inverse, note that the sequence
$$
{x_i \choose i },\quad 1\leq i\leq k
$$
is increasing in $i$ (being a subsequence of the diagonal of the pascal's triangle).

So given the position, since you know $k$ just find the *largest* quantity of the form $x \choose k$ which obeys
$${x \choose k} \leq \textrm{Position}(W).$$
The value of $x$ which is the largest is your $x_k.$ Then find the largest $x$ which obeys
$$
{x \choose k} + {x_k \choose k} \leq \textrm{Position}(W)
$$
which is your $x_{k-1},$ and so on recursively, for $k$ steps.

Comment: Apologies for responding so late, I haven't had the time yet to write this out in code, I'll keep you posted!

Comment: I've read the original paper by Tom Cover, but I struggle to wrap my head around how the inverse function works, that is, to get the word W by its index. Would you mind elaborating on that part a bit?

Comment: see my edit please